# Facing error while sending Mail in ASP.NET 3.5(VS.NET 2008), through gmail account

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, gmail

I have tried various useful code provided by various programmers. I found 1 easy to use, and tried to design a contact form. Its working fine while deploying in VS.NET 2008. But when I publish it onto the web server, it is showing "Timed Out Error".

I have also set the Trust Level to full in the Hosting Server(GoDaddy).
Also, tried this inside web.config file.

Still, not working.

Here is the Code :

```
protected void SendMail()
{
    string fromAddress = "abc@gmail.com";// Gmail Address from where you send the mail
    string toAddress = "xyz@gmail.com";
    const string fromPassword = "password";//Password of your gmail address
    string subject = "Enquiry from Website Contact Form.";
    string body = "From: " + txtName.Text + "\n";
    body += "Email: " + txtEmail.Text + "\n";
    body += "Contact: " + txtPhone.Text + "\n";
    body += "Message: \n" + txtMessage.Text + "\n";
    lblMsgSend.Visible = true;
    try
    {
        var smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
        {
            smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            smtp.Port = 587;
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress, fromPassword);
            smtp.Timeout = 20000;
        }
        smtp.Send(fromAddress, toAddress, subject, body);
        Response.Write("Message sent successfully.");
        lblMsgSend.Text = "Message sent successfully.";
    }
    catch (System.Net.Mail.SmtpException se)
    {
        lblMsgSend.Text = "Message sending failed. Details : " + se.Message.ToString() + se.StackTrace.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblMsgSend.Text = "Message sending failed. Details : " + ex.Message.ToString() + ex.StackTrace.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Their firewall is probably blocking you.

Comment: How could I check the firewall setting for a Web Server(for Godaddy in this case).